# Set cursor position when input is onFocus?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input, onfocus

I need to set cursor (caret) to **1st position when input is focused:**

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-fast-l2x85?file=/src/App.tsx)

I guess the following code should be working, but it's not. It works if it's triggered by a button click, though.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import React, { ChangeEventHandler, useRef, useState } from "react";

const setCaretPosition = (ctrl, pos) => {
  // Modern browsers
  if (ctrl.setSelectionRange) {
    ctrl.focus();
    ctrl.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
  }
};

export default function App() {
  
  const [value,setValue] = useState("123456789");
  const input_ref = useRef(null);

  const onFocus = () => {
    setCaretPosition(input_ref.current, 0);
  };

  const onChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

  const buttonClick = () => {
    setCaretPosition(input_ref.current, 0);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        <input 
          type="text" 
          onChange={onChange} 
          value={value} 
          ref={input_ref}
          onFocus={onFocus}
        />
        <button onClick={buttonClick}>Reset cursor</button>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: Using your CodeSandbox link, it works fine for me in Firefox. I click the text input and the cursor is at the beginning.

Comment: weird you would refocus the cursor after the user sets it

Comment: @epascarello there will be a mask of type `DD-MM-YYYY` present. So I'd like to make sure the cursor is at the begining. On mobile is usually harder to select the exact beginning of the mask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual issue with onFocus not with your code it seems that your code put the cursor at beginning and then focus event puts it back to end. So postponing your code firing after focus puts the cursor at end resolves the issue.

I tried to put it in `setTimeout`, it started working right away. - Tested with your code sandbox

```
setTimeout(() => {
      setCaretPosition(input_ref.current as HTMLInputElement, 0);
})
```